# Types of singularities of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is a pole of $f$. Prove that $z$ is an essential singularity of $g:=e^{f}$.

I thought we need to porve that $z$ is neither a removable singular nor a pole of $g$. But when I looked at the limit of $|g|$ at $z$, I can not decide whether it converges or not. And there is also a hint: consider the image of $g$, I don't know how the image of $g$ will help?

Comment: consider $f(z) = \frac{1}{z} + \sin(z)$ , how do you prove that $e^{f(z)}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0 $ ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is ok to expand $e^{f}$ using Laurent series, if I can, then z is automatically an essential singularity, but I don't think it is that easy...

Comment: if you already proved the Laurent series theorems, yes you can. but what I wanted to show you is that you only have to prove two things : that $e^{f(z)}$ is holomorphic on $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ (so that $z=0$ is an isolated singularity) and that $z=0$ is not a pole, for example by showing that on some path converging to $z=0$ :  $|e^{f(z)}|$ grows much faster than $\frac{1}{|z|^k}$ for any $k > 0$.

Comment: so once you proved that $f(z) = \sum_{n= - \infty}^\infty c_n z^n$ for every $0 < |z| < \epsilon$, with $|c_n| \not\to 0$ when $n \to \infty$, then the two points are automatically proven, and $z=0$ is an essential singularity.

Comment: (and note that any entire function  $h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$ with $|c_n| \not \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$ is not bounded by any polynomial is the [extended Liouville theorem and needs a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)#Remarks))